# New class with arrays and a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to Xcode, and I'm trying to create a class with arrays and a dictionary. I don't understand how to correctly initialize the object. What am I doing wrong?

**"maindata.h"**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface maindata : NSDictionary
{
    NSDictionary *maindict;
    NSArray      *arrayofallmethods;
    NSArray      *categories;
    NSArray      *methods;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *maindict;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray      *categories;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray      *methods;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString     *pathtoplist;


+(maindata *) shareddata;

@end
```

**"maindata.m"**

```
#import "maindata.h"

@implementation maindata

@synthesize maindict;
@synthesize methods;
@synthesize categories;
@synthesize pathtoplist;

static maindata *shareddata_;

-(id)init
{
    if(self == [super init])
    {
        pathtoplist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"allData" ofType:@"plist"];
        shareddata_.maindict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathtoplist];
        shareddata_.methods = [maindict allValues];
    }

    return shareddata_;
}

+(maindata *) shareddata
{
    if (!shareddata_)
    {
        shareddata_ = [[maindata alloc] init];
    }

    return shareddata_;
}

@end
```

Comment: r u getting any error.?! ur question dont specify what problem is or what u want? maindict is NSDictionary; but in the init method u r allocating it using NSMutableDictionary.?? check that also

Comment: I have tried to create one valid class. Please refer it. hope that helps...

Comment: Class names should always be in `UpperCamelCase`. This is the convention, and the Cocoa framework relies on these conventions sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

What you created here seems to be singleton object. If you did it intetionally, it's fine. However to normally initialize an object you should use just `-(id)init` method without static shared stuff.

So basically you should follow Jim's answer. Notice the line

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self == [super init]){}
}
```

is not a comparison, but assignment, so it should look like this

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init]){}
}
```

alternatively, to avoid compiler warnings, you can write

```
-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//maindata.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface maindata : NSObject{
         NSDictionary *maindict;
         NSArray      *arrayofallmethods;
         NSArray      *categories;
         NSArray      *methods;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *maindict; 
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *categories;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *methods;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray * arrayofallmethods;
@end


//"maindata.m"

import "maindata.h"
@implementation maindata
@synthesize maindict;
@synthesize methods;
@synthesize categories;
@synthesize arrayofallmethods;

-(id)init {
      if(self = [super init]){
          NSString *pathtoplist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"allData" ofType:@"plist"];
          maindict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathtoplist];
          methods = [maindict allValues];
    }
    return self;
 }
@end
```

And from other class try to initialize and create object of maindata class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "maindata.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     maindata *objMainData = [[maindata alloc]init];
     // use object here for more operations on your data.
}
```